# Why added mock module is not executed in nested beforeEach

Tags: angularjs, mocking, protractor, jasmine2.0

I have the following spec:

```
describe("parent describe", function(){

  beforeEach(function(){
    loginPage.go();
  });

  describe("nested describe", function(){

    beforeEach(function(){
      browser.addMockModule("httpMocker", function() {
        console.log("going there ?"); //not executed in the browser, WHY ?
        angular.module("httpMocker", ["ngMockE2E"]).run( function($httpBackend) {
          $httpBackend.whenGET(/security/).respond( function() { return [401]; });

        $httpBackend.whenGET(/.*/).passThrough();
      });
    });

    it("a spec", function(){
      //....
    })
  });
});
```

As the comment mention it, the function given to addMockModule never get executed in the browser.

Now, if I move the `addMockModule` call in the `beforeEach` of the parent `describe`, the mocked module get added and executed.

Why that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to the `beforeEach()` place. The [`addMockModule`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=Protractor.prototype.addMockModule) has to be called before any `browser.get()` call:

> **Add a module to load before Angular whenever Protractor.get is called**. Modules will be registered after existing modules already on
>   the page, so any module registered here will override preexisting
>   modules with the same name.

In your case, I'm pretty sure the `loginPage.go();` uses `browser.get()`.